# Making a beautiful gallery from just thumbnails

Tags: jquery, gallery

I am trying to make a gallery that has a fixed html markup that I cannot change. All the modifications I make to this gallery should be with javascript.

**My Goal:**

To make a gallery from thumbnails that contains the larger version of the image in it's href and show it above the thumbnails on clicking the thumbnail.

In short, I want to turn this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3y4P.png
into this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vJ9y.jpg

**Limitation:**

My jQuery knowledge is very limited.

**What I have so far:**

You can see what I have developed so far in this live jsbin: http://jsbin.com/eYubAdOy/1

the whole thing is working partially with some bugs. I have added comments for each actions for better understanding.

**BUGS:**

1. The second images has a caption; the caption of the second image should be visible only when the second thumbnail is clicked. but, on loading the page, the caption is shown on first image.
2. the ajax gif that I added with lazyload doesnt seem to end loading when you load the page.

I would be grateful if someone could help me fix this. and I would also like to know how would you write the whole thing?

Thanks

Comment: i would suggesst you ask a particular coding question rather then showing what you have and ask for any improvements..

Comment: you need to start lazyload after you prepend #mainImage and for the first thumb you need to check .gallery-item:eq(0) like this [http://jsbin.com/adaQATa/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/adaQATa/1/edit)

Comment: Lovely! works flawlessly. can you add this as answer and let me mark your answer as correct answer? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to start lazyload after you create the #mainImage like this

```
//Prepend the big image area. and load the src image of the first thumbnail. The.ast_full is for fancybox integration.
jQuery(".thn_post_wrap .gallery").prepend("<div class='ast_gall'>    
        <a href='"+first_image+"' class='ast_full' title='See larger version of this image'>
        </a><span class='ast_cap'></span>    
        <img id='mainImage' src='"+base+"/wp-content/themes/asteria_lite/images/newloader.gif' data-original='"+first_image+"' class='gallery_full'/>
        </div>");
//lazyload the big images
jQuery("#mainImage").lazyload();
```

to fix the caption you need to change this

```
//if the first thumbail image has caption inside of it, add the caption text to our empty .ast_cap span tag that we appended earlier.
jQuery(".ast_cap").html(jQuery('.has_cap:eq(0) .gallery-caption').html());
```

for this

```
if(jQuery('.gallery-item:eq(0) .gallery-caption').length>0){
  jQuery(".ast_cap").html(jQuery('.gallery-item:eq(0) .gallery-caption').html());
}else{
  jQuery(".ast_cap").css("display","none");//hide .ast_cap if it is empty 
}
```

http://jsbin.com/adaQATa/1/edit